# Sharepoint URL redirection

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin

I am trying to achieve URL redirection i want to know different possibilities to achieve this.

Scenario: I have created sharepoint web application(2013, host header site collection) with Annonymous access enabled and NTLM(windows authentication enabled--- Both are enabled). I have bind this site to certificate also and its working as expected if i browse the site with https://test.com

but if i just browse the site with http://test.com its asking me for user name and password. This i want to avoid even if i try to access http my requirement is it should redirect to https.

I have entered username and password and returns 200 http status.

I know there are options we can achieve this 
1) IIS redirect
2) Through custom code snippet (C#/Javascript)

But apart from this is there any way we can achieve this like load balance  or DNS etc

Your guidence will be really help full.

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by addin an AAM (Alternate Access Mapping) setting in  a sharepoint site.

Try to convert an Https request to the http in that. I haven't tried it myself so I am not sure if this will work or not, but there are some examples of a reverse which you want.

For your reference this is a link to make it for http to https

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64484/http-to-https-redirection-using-aam

Let me know the outcome.